# installing python netsnmp on centos 7

Tags: python, net-snmp

I am getting this error `fatal error: net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h: No such file or directory`. I have installed `gcc, python-devel, net-snmp, net-snmp-utils, net-snmp-python` and other development dependencies.

```
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
[admin@localhost python]$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.5.2/net-snmp-5.5.2.tar.gz
[admin@localhost python]$ pwd
/tmp/net-snmp-5.5.2/python
[admin@localhost python]$ python setup.py build
sh: net-snmp-config: command not found
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp
copying netsnmp/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp
copying netsnmp/client.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp/tests
copying netsnmp/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp/tests
copying netsnmp/tests/test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp/tests
running build_ext
building 'netsnmp.client_intf' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/admin/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/include/python2.7 -c netsnmp/client_intf.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/netsnmp/client_intf.o
netsnmp/client_intf.c:9:38: fatal error: net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
[admin@localhost python]$
```

**UPDATE1:** After running `./configure && make && make install` on the netsnmp source dir, I was able to run `python setup.py install`. However, now I am getting this error from python:

```
>>> import netsnmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "netsnmp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from client import *
  File "netsnmp/client.py", line 1, in <module>
    import client_intf
ImportError: No module named client_intf
>>>
```

**UPDATE2:** My bad!! I was running python interpreter from the directory of netsnmp source dir `cd /tmp/net-snmp-master/python/` which was causing me to give the expected error as python was not using the import from the egg, but from the source. Anyways, after doing a `cd ~`, I am getting a new error

```
>>> import netsnmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netsnmp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    #
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netsnmp/client.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netsnmp/client_intf.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netsnmp/client_intf.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libnetsnmp.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> exit()
```

**UPDATE3**

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo ldconfig
[root@localhost ~]# sudo ldconfig -p | grep netsnmp
    libnetsnmptrapd.so.31 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmptrapd.so.31
    libnetsnmptrapd.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmptrapd.so
    libnetsnmpmibs.so.31 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmpmibs.so.31
    libnetsnmpmibs.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmpmibs.so
    libnetsnmphelpers.so.31 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmphelpers.so.31
    libnetsnmphelpers.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmphelpers.so
    libnetsnmpagent.so.31 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmpagent.so.31
    libnetsnmpagent.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmpagent.so
    libnetsnmp.so.31 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmp.so.31
    libnetsnmp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnetsnmp.so
[root@localhost ~]# find / -name libnetsnmp.so*
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.31
/usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.31.0.2
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.30.0.3
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.30.0.1
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so
/usr/local/lib/libnetsnmp.so.30
[root@localhost ~]#
```

**UPDATE4**: Finally fixed the problem by running `sudo ldconfig` and modifying `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
[root@localhost ~]# cat > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf <<EOF
> /usr/local/lib
> EOF
[root@localhost ~]# ldconfig
[root@localhost ~]# python
>>> import netsnmp
>>> exit()
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed net-snmp-devel.
Check the existing of /usr/include/net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h

Comment: I just did `yum install net-snmp-devel`. But even before that, I actually was able to atleast build and install the python binding by 1st running `./configure; make; make install` from the netsnmp source. However I get the following error now: `ImportError: No module named client_intf` when i try imporing netsnmp

Comment: I don't understand what is the use of `net-snmp-python`?? I don't see any python packages being installed

Comment: Have you tried python setup.py install? Also you can find netsnmp in net-snmp-5.5.2/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 after the build.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i did... `python setup.py install` but i get ImportError for `client_intf`

Comment: oops..., ya i updated the question again... let me try the ldconfig, but on what?

Comment: just sudo ldconfig to renew libraries cache. The sudo ldconfig -p | grep netsnmp

Comment: I get the same error... here is the output in the question UPDATE3

Comment: Try to add  /usr/local/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf then run sudo ldconfig again